# How to stop the user from using the app when the status is set to disabled/lost/stolen in IBM Mobilefirst console

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am using a native Android and IOS app which connects to Mobilefirst server. The app is connecting to MFP server for App authenticity and for creating user identity(Adapter authentication).

Now when I went console/devices

- I see status specific to device which contains Active, Lost, Stolen, Expired and Disabled.
- And under installed apps I see status Enabled and disabled. I see Certificate Serial Number value being No certificate. Do I need to add anything to get this certificate will this matter to enable or disable the status of the app.

My question is how do I use these features in Native apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start by reading the documentation. You can go ahead and start reading here: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.monitor.doc/monitor/c_device_mgmt.html

It has nothing to do with programming so I'm not going to write anymore about this in Stack Overflow (it is too much to cover anyway).